# Cannot update textfield in delegate callback method

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have implemented delegate in `LoginViewController` defined in `RegistrationViewController`. Callback function is calling but the problem is that I am not able to update the `textfield` of `LoginViewController` in delegate method.

**LoginViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController :UIViewController,RegisterViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mobileNumber: UITextField!

    @IBAction func showRegistrationView(_ sender: Any) {

     let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "registration") as! RegistrationViewController
       controller.delegate = self
     present(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    func onUserRegistrationCompletion(number: String) {
            print(number) // output is 05010101010
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.mobileNumber.text! = number
            print(self.mobileNumber.text!) . // output is empty
        }

    }



}
```

**RegistrationViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

    class RegistrationViewController: UIViewController {

        weak var delegate:RegisterViewDelegate?

        @IBAction func register(_ sender: Any) {
            self.delegate?.onUserRegistrationCompletion(number: "05010101010")
            let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "login")
            present(controller!, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }

    }


    protocol RegisterViewDelegate:class {
        func onUserRegistrationCompletion(number:String)
    }
```

Comment: What is the output of this line: print(self.mobileNumber.text!) and print(number)

Comment: it is crashing or jusr value is not populating ??

Comment: App is running without any error. 

print(number) //05010101010
print(self.mobileNumber.text!)  // empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it means you allocating the memory again on `self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "login")` in Register VC, that the reason your delegate is by default goes to nil.

```
@IBAction func register(_ sender: Any) {
        self.delegate?.onUserRegistrationCompletion(number: "05010101010")
         self.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil) 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `navigationController`.

and you can push to next view this way:

```
let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "registration") as! RegistrationViewController
controller.delegate = self
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

and when you want to go back to previous view use this code:

```
self.delegate?.onUserRegistrationCompletion(number: "05010101010")
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

And your result will be:

[image]

Check [THIS](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=94373598663222975082) sample for more info.

And don't forget to Embed In your `LoginViewController` into `navigationController` from storyboard. as shown in demo project.